# Trying to parse HTML using BeautifulSoup, but it not working?

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I have to parse this HTML:

`<a href="rtsp://v8.cache2.c.youtube.com/CjgLENy73wIaLwnqnxbpjjoGIRMYESARFEIJbXYtZ29vZ2xlSARSB3Jlc3VsdHNgpq6joefRgbhNDA==/0/0/0/video.3gp"><img src="http://i.ytimg.com/vi/IQY6jukWn-o/default.jpg?w=80&amp;h=60&amp;sigh=izeIwhz4POtPOOr-jRGrtC4qiFA" alt="video" width="80" height="60" style="border:0;margin:0px;" /></a>`

I am looking for all the links ending with `.3gp`.

I am using BeautifulSoup and it really makes me mad, many things didn't work like if you search for a specific text, it always return empty list.

Have tried:

```
comment = soup.find(text=re.compile(".3gp"))
```

Comment: comment = soup.find(text=re.compile(".3gp"))

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you search for [`text`](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/documentation.html#arg-text) you are looking for all of the `NavigableString` objects that match your regular expression (Which is looking for any character followed by a `3`, a `g` and a `b` -- use `\.3agb` if you want to match `.3agb` literally with a regex).

Use `soup.findAll` and search for any `<a>` tags with an `href` that match what you want in this way:

```
soup.findAll('a', attrs={'href': re.compile(".3gp")})
#or
soup.findAll('a', href=re.compile(".3gp"))
```

**SEE:** http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/documentation.html#The basic find method: findAll(name, attrs, recursive, text, limit, **kwargs)

Comment: 'video_tags = page.findAll('a')
video_list=[]
for video_tag in video_tags:
        url = video_tag.get('href')
        video_list.append(url)'

Answer (score 0):

For this particular problem, Regular Expressions are probably good enough.
I know about [RegEx match open tags except XHTML self-contained tags](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/) (the first answer is awsumness) but this problem seems like a quick hack needed to do something totally different

```
In [1]: import re

In [2]: a = """...THE TEXT YOU PASTED.."""

In [3]: re.findall('".*?3gp"', a)
Out[3]: ['"rtsp://v8.cache2.c.youtube.com/CjgLENy73wIaLwnqnxbpjjoGIRMYESARFEIJbXYtZ29vZ2xlSARSB3Jlc3VsdHNgpq6joefRgbhNDA==/0/0/0/video.3gp"']
```

Comment: Not printing anything, I am getting the data from url not from a defined string.

Answer (score 0):

Pyparsing's makeHTMLTags expression will give you results similar to regex, but with automatic results names (like named groups), and tolerance of many HTML idiosyncracies:

```
>>> from pyparsing import *
>>>
>>> h = """<a href="rtsp://v8.cache2.c.youtube.com/CjgLENy73wIaLwnqnxbpjjoGIRMYE
SARFEIJbXYtZ29vZ2xlSARSB3Jlc3VsdHNgpq6joefRgbhNDA==/0/0/0/video.3gp"><img src="h
ttp://i.ytimg.com/vi/IQY6jukWn-o/default.jpg?w=80&amp;h=60&amp;sigh=izeIwhz4POtP
OOr-jRGrtC4qiFA" alt="video" width="80" height="60" style="border:0;margin:0px;"
 /></a>"""
>>>
>>> aTag = makeHTMLTags("A")[0]
>>> result = aTag.parseString(h)
>>> print result.dump()
['A', ['href', 'rtsp://v8.cache2.c.youtube.com/CjgLENy73wIaLwnqnxbpjjoGIRMYESARFEIJbXYtZ29vZ2xlSARSB3Jlc3VsdHNgpq6joefRgbhNDA==/0/0/0/video.3gp'], False]
- empty: False
- href: rtsp://v8.cache2.c.youtube.com/CjgLENy73wIaLwnqnxbpjjoGIRMYESARFEIJbXYtZ29vZ2xlSARSB3Jlc3VsdHNgpq6joefRgbhNDA==/0/0/0/video.3gp
- startA: ['A', ['href', 'rtsp://v8.cache2.c.youtube.com/CjgLENy73wIaLwnqnxbpjjoGIRMYESARFEIJbXYtZ29vZ2xlSARSB3Jlc3VsdHNgpq6joefRgbhNDA==/0/0/0/video.3gp'], False]
  - empty: False
  - href: rtsp://v8.cache2.c.youtube.com/CjgLENy73wIaLwnqnxbpjjoGIRMYESARFEIJbXYtZ29vZ2xlSARSB3Jlc3VsdHNgpq6joefRgbhNDA==/0/0/0/video.3gp
>>> print result.href
rtsp://v8.cache2.c.youtube.com/CjgLENy73wIaLwnqnxbpjjoGIRMYESARFEIJbXYtZ29vZ2xlSARSB3Jlc3VsdHNgpq6joefRgbhNDA==/0/0/0/video.3gp
```

If you have many anchor tags, and just want those ending in ".3gp" then do:

```
>>> _3gp_links = [a.href for a in aTag.searchString(h) if a.href.endswith(".3gp")]
```